# nextjs doesn't execute server side code when using back/forward on safari(chrome/edge - iphone too)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, safari

I'm using nextjs 9, and i'm calling fetch inside getInititalProps and pass into component.

It works well on computer but when i'm using safari to test, some errors threw.

I try to debug and found out that server side code doesn't work or something. Cause data to map into client side components is all undefined.

So is there any way or solution to this problem.

By the way, i'm using remotedebug_ios_webkit_adapter to logging from safari to my pc's edge. On the pc i still can log but safari only log error without any log like my pc have.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/3065#issuecomment-416390035

Comment: But he just mention about the problem, is there any solutions